# Kotlin replaceWith an invoke operator

Tags: kotlin

I have an interface where I would like to notify users to use `invoke` operator instead of `oldFunction`.

```
interface SomeInterface {

  operator fun invoke(param: A)

  @Deprecated("Old stuff", ReplaceWith("invoke(param)"))
  fun oldFunction(param: A)

}
```

This currently works, but it replaces the `oldFunction` with `invoke` call in place. What I would like is to have it replace the `invoke` call with invoke operator `()`. Is this possible ? I'm using Android Studio 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
@Deprecated("Old stuff", ReplaceWith("this(param)"))
fun oldFunction(param: A)
```

Comment: Thanks this almost does the trick. Side effect of this is that the caller `this` get's also wrapped in paranthese resulting in something like `(caller)(param)`

Comment: @LubosMudrak IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 replaces `caller.oldFunction(param)` with `caller(param)` for me.

Comment: Ah @Bananon I just verified with IDEA 2019.3 and it works. In question I should have add a tag that the question is for AS 3.5. Will update the question and accept the response. Thanks!